# The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved

Tags: java, ftp-client

I am trying to read the file names using FTPClient. I have used commons-net-3.3.jar and commons-io-2.4.jar. But while executing, I am getting the following exceptions,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
Pattern cannot be resolved to a type
MatchResult cannot be resolved to a type
PatternMatcher cannot be resolved to a type
_matcher_ cannot be resolved
Perl5Matcher cannot be resolved to a type
pattern cannot be resolved
Perl5Compiler cannot be resolved to a type
MalformedPatternException cannot be resolved to a type
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
_matcher_ cannot be resolved
pattern cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
_matcher_ cannot be resolved
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field
result cannot be resolved or is not a field



at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl.<init>(RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl.java:19)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.ConfigurableFTPFileEntryParserImpl.<init>(ConfigurableFTPFileEntryParserImpl.java:57)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.UnixFTPEntryParser.<init>(UnixFTPEntryParser.java:136)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.UnixFTPEntryParser.<init>(UnixFTPEntryParser.java:119)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.createUnixFTPEntryParser(DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.java:169)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.createFileEntryParser(DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.java:94)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:2359)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2142)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2188)
at com.school.util.GetFileList.main(GetFileList.java:32)
```

Comment: how are you including the jar in as an external library in the project?

Comment: Where did you get those JAR files from? I cannot believe that you'd get them from Apache with unresolved compilation problems.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have an older version of commons-net which depends on Jakarta ORO in your classpath. Commons-net used to depend on ORO until version [1.4.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net/1.4.1).
If you are using Maven/Gradle/Ivy, make sure you do not get this version as a transitive dependency or another library.
Discarding this older version of commons-net should resolve the issue.

Comment: So make sure Ant is taking the correct version of commons-net. If the .jar name does not contain the version, you can check the one specified in its META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file

Comment: Thanks it worked with the correct version of the commons-net.