# FTP file access - java

Tags: java, file, exception, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have written a simple program that access FTP file details in java

package MyFTP;

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

public class TestClass2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

        String server = "192.168.100.1";
        int port = 26;
        String user = "username";
        String pass = "password";

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {

            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            //ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            FTPFile[] files = null;
            try {
                files = ftpClient.listFiles("/test"); ////**EXCEPTION**
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
    The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
    The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
    The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
    The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
    The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
    Pattern cannot be resolved to a type
    MatchResult cannot be resolved to a type
    PatternMatcher cannot be resolved to a type
    _matcher_ cannot be resolved
    Perl5Matcher cannot be resolved to a type
    pattern cannot be resolved
    Perl5Compiler cannot be resolved to a type
    MalformedPatternException cannot be resolved to a type
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    _matcher_ cannot be resolved
    pattern cannot be resolved or is not a field
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    _matcher_ cannot be resolved
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field

    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl.<init>(RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl.java:19)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.ConfigurableFTPFileEntryParserImpl.<init>(ConfigurableFTPFileEntryParserImpl.java:57)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.NTFTPEntryParser.<init>(NTFTPEntryParser.java:73)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.NTFTPEntryParser.<init>(NTFTPEntryParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.createNTFTPEntryParser(DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.createFileEntryParser(DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:2359)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2142)
    at MyFTP.TestClass2.main(TestClass2.java:36)
```

Don't know what I have done wrong

I have a file at

> ftp://192.168.100.1:26/test/a.txt

Am I correct with the line

> files = ftpClient.listFiles("/test");

Need help ,
Thanks in advance

jars used:

> commons-net-3.3.jar commons.io_2.0.1.jar apache-commons-net.jar

Comment: You program doesn't compile correctly. Make sure that the org.apache stuff you need is complete - which it apparently isn't.

Comment: it looks like you have problems with the dependencies. how do you import the libraries in the project? manually, maven , ant?

Comment: just added manually, seems thats what the problem

Comment: You are using a very old version of apache.commons.net.ftp. 1.4.1 vs. 3.3. Discard the old stuff, get the new version and see how it goes.

Comment: @laune  see the jars I'm using updated my answer

Comment: @zlobi.wan.kenobi pls see my jars I'm using in updated ans

Comment: Move apache-commons-net.jar out of the way and try with the others.

Comment: thanks  @laune prob solved..:)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756090/the-import-org-apache-oro-cannot-be-resolved